# How to compare 2 text files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to be able compare the contents of 2 text files and see if the contents of those files are the same. If the contents of the 2 files are different,  I need this powershell script to send me an email with a list of differences from the 2 files. Here is my code:

```
$fromaddress = "noreply@xy.com"
$toaddress = "me@xy.com "
$Subject = "Comparing 2 text files"
$login = "abc"
$password = "12345" | Convertto-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$smtpserver = "smtp.office.com" 
$message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.From = $fromaddress
$message.To.Add($toaddress)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True
$message.Subject = $Subject
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
$message.Attachments.Add($attach)
$message.body = $body
$message.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver, 587)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($login, $password);


IF (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $dir\file1.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $dir\file2.txt)){
        Write-Output "The files are different "
        $smtp.Send($message);
    } 
    Else {
        Write-Output "The files are not different" 
    }
```

I have looked at different online resources that suggested the use of `Compare-Object` cmdlet but it doesn't seem to work in my situation. The problem with my code is that, its returning everything from file1. Any one who knows why this is not working for me?

Comment: Get a hash of each file and compare those. Use `Get-FileHash`

Comment: @EBGreen Thanks for responding, can you please clarify where in the code do I place the Get-FileHash? Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Well, I would suggest that you start by opening a powershell prompt and type `Get-Help Get-FileHash -Detail`. Having said that I see that you also have an issue with what is actually in the email. You set the body of the message to `$body` but I don't see anywhere in your code that you define what `$body` is.

Comment: @EBGreen The emailing $body part is not a major problem. I just noticed that I didn't include the $body in my code pasted above. The problem is that I need this email to contain an attachment with the differences between the 2 files. In this case am getting everything from file1.

Comment: In that case, how are you creating `$attach`? It is really hard to help you with your problem if you don't show the code that causes the problem.

Comment: With your code in the `if` I only get the `Write-Output`  nothing else. Beside, `-ReferenceObject` and `-DifferenceObject` need only be written out if not in positional order and if written out, can be abbreviated as long they are uniquely identifiable `-Ref` , `-Diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This scans the 2 text files for differences and pipes it to a third File**

```
$File1 = "C:\Scripts\Txt1.txt"

$File2 = "C:\Scripts\Txt2.txt"

$Location = "C:\Scripts\Txt3.txt"

compare-object (get-content $File1) (get-content $File2) | format-list | Out-File $Location
```

---

Output:
[image]

Comment: The small window of `Txt3.txt` doesn't show the present SideIndicator `=>`

Answer (score 1):

To compare two file and determine if they are identical use a file hash:

```
$hash1 = Get-FileHash $dir\file1.txt
$hash2 = Get-FileHash $dir\file2.txt
if($hash1 -eq $hash2){
    'They are the same'
}else{
    'They are NOT the same
}
```

Comment: Just to mention it, `Compare-Object` will by default ignore case differences, the hash can't.

Answer (score -1):

You're almost right with your initial script. You just need to add -IncludeEqual

See below. Text files 1 & 2 are just "hi there." Text file 3 is "hi there2"

```
$1 = gc 'H:\Skype Migrations\file1.txt'
$2 = gc 'H:\Skype Migrations\file2.txt'
$3 = gc 'H:\Skype Migrations\file3.txt'

IF ( ( Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $1 -DifferenceObject $3 -IncludeEqual ).sideindicator -ne "==" )
   { Write-Output "The files are different " } 
Else 
   { Write-Output "The files are not different" }
```

Edited to showcase how to use the IncludeEqual

Comment: How would `-IncludeEqual` fix the problem of the differences not being shown?